# How to to implementing only one methods from abstract class out of two abstract methods in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

In an Abstract class there are two abstract methods Method1() and Method2(),
but I like to inherit only one Method1() in derived Class, how to handle the situation?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void Method1();

    public abstract void Method2();
}
```

Comment: That's not really how inheritance works.  Maybe you meant to define these methods in interfaces and selectively implement those interfaces in any given class?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect this is an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are trying to do something to fix a completely different problem that can probably be solved in a better way. Try posting a new question with the actual problem you are facing and let us help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really you can't... If you ***have*** to (and I would really question the reasons) some options are:

If you do not have any control over the abstract classes involved, and must use this specific abstract class, then, only way is to make the implementation in derived class throw a `NotImplementedException`.

```
 public MyDerivedClass: BaseClass
 {
     public override void Method1()
     {
          // implementation of Method1
     }
     public override void Method2()
     { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
 }
```

... or create another abstract base class called, say `OnlyDOMethod1`

```
 public abstract class OnlyDoMethod1
 { public abstract void Method1(); }
```

then, modify `Baseclass` so it inherits from `OnlyDoMethod1`

```
 public abstract class BaseClass: OnlyDoMethod1
 {  public abstract void Method2(); }
```

and use `OnlyDoMethod1` anywhere you only want `Method1`

```
public MyDerivedClass: OnlyDoMethod1
{
   public override void Method1()
   {
      // implementation of Method1
   }
}
```

Comment: `to make the implementation in derived class throw a NotImplementedException.` - not very good advise for future readers

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is interfaces.  Something like this:

```
public interface ICanDoMethod1
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface ICanDoMethod2
{
    void Method2();
}
```

Then in your classes you can selectively implement them:

```
public class JustMethod1 : ICanDoMethod1
{
    // implement Method1 here
}

public class Both : ICanDoMethod1, ICanDoMethod2
{
    // implement both here
}

// etc.
```

Essentially, any given class either can or can not be polymorphically interpreted as any given type.  If you want to be only *part* of a type, then what you really have is two types.  C# is single-inheritance, so to implement multiple types you would use interfaces.

---

Conversely, you could also chain your inheritance.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class Base1
{
    public abstract void Method1();
}

public abstract class BaseBoth : Base1
{
    public abstract void Method2();
}

public class JustOne : Base1
{
    // only implement Method1 here
}

public class Both : BaseBoth
{
    // implement both here
}
```

That'll work if the options stack, that is if you don't want to be able to pick and choose and either want "1" or "1 and 2" (but not just "2").

---

As a last resort, you *can* "selectively implement" methods by explicitly not implementing the others.  It would looks something like:

```
public class JustOne : BaseClass
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        // implement
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But this would be something of an anti-pattern, where your objects would advertise functionality that they intentionally do not support.  This would mean that the type `BaseClass` should be considered very unstable/unreliable, because there's no way for anything consuming that type to know how it *should* actually behave.

---

Ultimately, it sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner with your types and you need to back up a little and re-think them.  Liskov Substitution shouldn't be taken so lightly.

Comment: Why you even bothered to advise "bad practice"? :)

Comment: @Fabio: It's an option, just not a great one.  There could be some edge case in the OP's system where it might be necessary, at least in the short term.  I'd rather describe it and describe why not to use it than just say "can't be done" and let the OP find that option on their own and think they've discovered something clever :)

Comment: I think this can't be an option. Imagine your reaction when your need to be working with library where some methods throws `NotImplementedException`

Answer (score 1):

This is basic example of violation of one of SOLID principles `Interface segregation principle`

> A client should never be forced to implement an interface that it
>   doesn’t use or clients shouldn’t be forced to depend on methods they
>   do not use

If you have abstraction where you need only some of method you need to split them in separated abstractions.

.NET do not support multi-inheritance from classes, nut have nice workaround for this problem -> interfaces.

If you care about your code, then you have only one option - split abstract class into two separated classes which have only one method.

If you work only with abstraction then interfaces is better approach, because you can implement multiply interfaces in one class.

```
public interface IMethodOne
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface IMethodTwo
{
    void Method2();
}
```

Then you can implement that both interfaces in the class which needs both methods. And use only one interface in the class with one method needs.

```
public abstract class BaseClass : IMethodOne, IMethodTwo
{
    public abstract void Method1();
    public abstract void Method2();
}
```

And class with one method

```
public abstract class BaseClassOneMethod : IMethodOne
{
    public abstract void Method1();
}
```